# Мешает автообновление страницы при сохранении файлов в React приложении

Tags: php, reactjs, axios, create-react-app

У меня есть форма в которой есть несколько полей и одно из этих полей служит для загрузки изображений. Когда я загружаю новое изображение в папку /uploads, то после загрузки страница обновляется, потому-что было добавлено новое изображение, и я не успеваю нажать на кнопку отправки. Как можно избежать этих обновлений?

Comment: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html ответы на все вопросы

Comment: У меня просто изображения отправляются на php и php уже сохраняет в папку.

Comment: Мне кажется, тут никто не знает, что значит "отправить изображение на php". Давайте вопрос нормально сформулируем?

Comment: Я написал метод, в котором формируется запрос с изображениями и который отправляет этот сформированный ajax-запрос на php файл. PHP сохраняет это изображение в папку и возвращает в обратно название изображения (Это название я использую для предпросмотра изображения перед отправкой в базу данных). После загрузки изображения в папку страница сразу же перезагружается(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по комментарию под вопрос, Вам нужно сделать предпросмотра изображения. Лучше всего не отправлять изображение, а сразу показать изображение перед отправкой формы. В этом поможет объект `new FileReader()`.

Comment: Забыл написать Вам спасибо! :D Это решение мне помогло!

Comment: Тогда отметь, что ответ был получен.